# Binding Array.push

Tags: javascript

I was trying to pass the 'push' method of array directly to forEach invocation on another array:

```
result = []
l1 = [1]
f = result.push.bind(result)
l1.forEach(f)
```

And the result ends up:

```
> result
[ 1, 0, [ 1 ] ]
```

If I do, instead:

```
l1.forEach(function (x) { f(x); })
```

Then everything works fine. What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand what is going on run this code snipped

```
[1].forEach(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

And you'll receive

```
[1, 0, Array[1]]
```

Function, supplied to `forEach` method is called for each array element with the following arguments:

1. Array element
2. Element position
3. Array itself

So, it seems like you can't do what you want with binding a `push` call to specific array instance...

Comment: Doh, it totally did not occur to me that forEach can pass 3 arguments. Thanks!